# Keeping output on the same line

Tags: powershell

I want to keep the output of this command on the same line:

```
((Get-ADUser -filter {employeetype -eq "Employee"}).SamAccountName) | Sort-Object | Get-ADUser | ForEach-Object {$_.Name,$_.Department,$_mail}
```

Currently the output shows up like this:

```
James Roberts
Accounting
jroberts@email.tld
```

But, I need to have it show up like:

```
James Roberts Accounting jroberts@email.tld
```

I've also tried using (based on a suggestion I found):

```
((Get-ADUser -filter {employeetype -eq "Employee"}).SamAccountName) | Sort-Object | Get-ADUser | ForEach-Object {$_.Name;$_.Department;$_mail}
```

but, I get the same three lines of output and not one line.

Comment: Instead of `Foreach-Object` you should use `Select-Object -Property`

Comment: to get those items on the same line, you can use `-join` with whatever delimiter you want. [*grin*] take a look at `Get-Help about_Join` for some useful examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create customized objects:

```bsh
… | Select-Object -Property Name,Department,Mail
```

If you want to make strings:

```bsh
… | ForEach-Object { $_.Name,$_.Department,$_.Mail -join " " }
```

If you just want to display the table nicely (not going to use this output afterwards):

```bsh
… | Format-Table -Property Name,Department,Mail -AutoSize
```